# What health problems can not a cat blood test reveal?

Tags: cats

After having blood in vomit, I had veterinarian to make a (costly 120 euro) blood test of my cat. 
The vet him/herself was not present when we got the cat, and according to the receptionist, they were not sure what was wrong with the cat: everything in their test seemed ok apart from a bit higher than normal white blood cell count and a bit of fever.

[image]

[image]

The prescription is a drug called `Emeprid` which I have to administer to the cat twice a day.

Now I'm wondering what major diseases have been ruled out by the blood test and what possible causes of the bloody vomiting may be hidden from the blood test?